# money_format - Negative number

Tags: php, money-format

I got the following code

```
#   On va convertir en somme monétaire
#   We convert our integer into a way to read money
$Vars['Income']     = money_format('%.2n', $Income);
$Vars['Spending']   = money_format('%.2n', $Spending);

#   On va calculer ce qui reste à dépenser
#   We do the math to know how much we can spend until the end of the month
$Vars['Remaining']  = money_format('%.2n', $Income - $Spending);
```

If `$Income - $Spending` is negative (under 0), then the income is lower then the spending. Alright. I am using my locale, french (canada) and the result for a negative number is (X,XX $).

Not having a - sign make non sense for me so I want to be able to output the number with a -0.00$ and not with (0.00$).

Example my income is 75.00$ and my spending are 100.00$. I spent 25$ more then I do so the remaining money will output (25.00$) but I want -25.00$.

I did try to add ( or + but I don't understand.

Thanks

UPDATE: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9dJ8.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Try not to spend more than your income! :)

Comment: I think you could use `sprintf('%.2f', ...` instead of `money_format` - that should give you the same format, but formatted as a float instead of as money.

Answer (score 5):

The format strings for [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) are a bit confusing.  What you want is:

```
money_format('%+.2n', $Income - $Spending);
```

Comment: @DavidBélanger - did you try with `sprintf` instead?

Comment: @andrewsi Yes, it work. I see the minus, but I could juste use number_format and append the $ symbol also... I wanted a function who does everything. I guess I'll just write one myself. I could rely on the user locale also.

Comment: @DavidBélanger: Maybe it's got something to do with your locale?

Comment: @Rocket Maybe but the first parameter isn't suppose to overwrite the locale ? Like my locale is set to use let's say () for negative number for if I write + should it use negative number ?

Comment: @DavidBélanger: That's what I thought too =/

Comment: @DavidBélanger: It may have something to do with `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'your_LOCALE');`

Comment: Yea. But the locale are working fine for the dates and I set the locale for `LC_ALL`... I'll look closer  and do some test.